# Reset gnome to its fresh post-install ubuntu 17.10 state

Tags: gnome, 17.10, themes

I did a fresh install of 17.10, and my desktop looked roughly like this:

[image: Fresh ubuntu]

Then, I started messing around and installed tweak tools, and [Zukitwo](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Zukitwo?content=140562). Then after a reboot I suddenly got a strange bar at the bottom like so:

[image: Strange task bar, and overall weird theme]

I'm trying to revert gnome to its earlier state, but nothing seems to work. I've tried the following commands:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Ambiance"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Ambiance"
dconf reset -f /
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
```

None of them bring me back to my begin state. I'm considering reinstalling completely, but hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Found my own answer. Turned out in my frenzy of trying random things, I had installed too many packages.

I removed the following packages:

`sudo apt-remove gnome-shell-extensions gnome-themes-standard-data gnome-themes-standard`

and after a reboot everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that system was switched to GNOME FlashBack.
Try to select Ubuntu on login screen.